# Is this Prince's Feather or Love Lies Bleeding?

Tags: identification

Last year, I planted from seed a mix of red flowering annuals. I did not notice any of those annuals selfseeding, except one. That one reprodeced itself all over the yard, several hundred times. The plant in question is, I gather, a red-purplish flowered amaranth. To my delight, it attracts butterflies. It is also edible, although I dont plan to eat it. At least it is not poisonous.. Is there a way to figure out the exact species, so that I know more about it.?

[image]

A view from above:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common name 'Prince's Feather' or 'Prince of Wales Feather' is used in some parts of the world for *Amaranthus hypochondriacus*, whereas 'love lies bleeding' is the common name for *Amaranthus caudatus*. They're just different varieties of the same plant - the one you show in the picture is not *A. hypochondriacus*, but a variety of *Amaranthus caudatus*, which usually has dark red flowers. The difference is the flowers dangle in *A. caudatus*, but are upright in *A. hypochondriacus*, see here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaranthus_hypochondriacus

Comment: But , then, what is it? Why can't it be a prince's feather?

Comment: &Jurp If I have queen annes lace, this must be prince of wales  feather, no?

Comment: is there any otherplant related to english kingdomship? i maight start collecting them as well.

Comment: See updated answer. As for other plants with common names relating to English kindgomship, pass, I have neither interest in nor patience with common names and don't know most of them anyway. It is always better to use the full botanical, Latin name, then the whole world knows which plant you mean.

Comment: In Ontario A. hypochondriacus grows to about 6 feet tall, has pendulous flowering stalks on bamboo-like canes and produces dark coloured seeds about the size of a peppercorn. Its height and hanging flowers give it the common label of "Kiss me over the garden gate" due to the fact that planted by a gate post the flowers will brush your face as you walk by. Sometimes known as prince's feather but much less commonly. Love lies bleeding is much smaller, 24", with much more densely packed flowers.

Comment: @Colin These are most likely seedlings of an amaranth that last year reached 6 feet. My climate is similar to Ontario climate.